# get json data from realtime database to Dialogflow inline editor (google assistant)

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Beginner here on programming, I'm working on my free time on a project which is related to Google Assistant, for the first time i'm using the Firebase Realtime Database and don't know how to get the data from there, the code below is in Dialogflow's inline editor, where is category1 2 and 3  inside those are students with credits. I have made some changes and put these three (categories1 2 and 3) in the database picture below, i want to remove these three categories from code and replace it with the ones in realtime database.

Because this is my first time using that database, I don't know how to get that data from there with nodejs.

```js
   
      function categoryac(agent) {
        const categories =  {
          category1: {"Alex" : 25, "Jennifer" : 45, "Justin" : 35, "Peter" : 89},
          category2: {"Alex" : 95, "Jennifer" : 75, "Justin" : 85, "Peter" : 59},
          category3: {"Alex" : 67, "Jennifer" : 55, "Justin" : 45, "Peter" : 15},
        };
        const categoried = agent.parameters["categoried"];
        const categoryAmount = agent.parameters["categoryAmount"];        
        const category = category[categoried];
        const aggregate = category[categoryAmount];       
        agent.add(`${categoried}'s ${categoryAmount} is ${aggregate}`); 
      }

      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('category', categoryac);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

[image]

UPDATE
I used the code below, like this:

```js
  

  function categoryac( agent ){
    const categoried = agent.parameters["categoried"];
    const categoryAmount = agent.parameters["categoryAmount"];
    var admin = require( 'firebase-admin' );
    admin.initializeApp( {
      credential: admin.credential.cert( {
        projectId: ' ',
        clientEmail: ' ',
        privateKey: ' '
      } ),
      dblink: 'www.*****.*****.com'
    } );
    var thing = admin.database();
    var  relating= thing.ref( `category/${categoried}/${categoryAmount}` );
    return relating.once( "value" ).then( snapshot =>{
      var aggregate = snapshot.value();
      agent.add( `${categoried}'s ${categoryAmount} is ${aggregate}` );
    } )
      .catch( fail =>{
        agent.add( 'uh oh, something went wrong.' );
        console.error( fail );
      } );
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set( 'category', categoryac );
  agent.handleRequest( intentMap );
} );
```

got error message : 'MalformedResponse
Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response.' error from log :

```js
{
 insertId:  "v*****2"  
 labels: {
  channel:  "preview"   
  querystream:  "GOOGLE_USER"   
  source:  "JSON_RESPONSE_VALIDATION"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/****/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-01-07T14:45:29.274840871Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   action_id:  "actions.intent.TEXT"    
   project_id:  "******"    
   version_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "assistant_action"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "MalformedResponse: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response"  
 timestamp:  "2019-01-07T14:45:29.266062732Z"  
 trace:  "projects/383182941858/traces/ABwppHFK_PehMj1XEs_Arng9VL7_zShy-EWvoziK0Ro6v74TaduNG1cJaRMnGAZMoLZhtILdG2hEBkDvJQ"  
}
```

Here is the error in the logs:

```
Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name. 
at FirebaseAppError.Error (native) 
at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28) 
at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28) 
at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:119:28) 
at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.initializeApp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:68:23) 
at FirebaseNamespace.initializeApp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:362:30) 
at categoryac (/user_code/index.js:34:11) 
at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44) 
at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:91:9) 
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you'll need to learn.

The first is how to [add the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to your project.

You'll also need to learn how to [retrieve the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) using the library. Firebase uses a reference-path based method to fetch the data, so you need to make sure you build the path correctly.

Finally, since you're doing this inside a fulfillment handler, and you are making an asynchronous call, you need to make sure you return a Promise. Fortunately, fetching the data also involves returning a Promise, so you can return this Promise.

The code might, partially, look something like this (untested):

```
  function personFacts(agent) {
    const personId = agent.parameters["personId"];
    const personMeasurement = agent.parameters["personMeasurement"];        

    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref(`person/${personId}/${personMeasurement}`);
    return ref.once("value")
      .then( snapshot => {
        var result = snapshot.val();
        agent.add(`${personId}'s ${personMeasurement} is ${result}`); 
      })
      .catch( err => {
        agent.add('uh oh, something went wrong.');
        console.error( err );
      });

  }
```

As you noted, you need to initialize the Firebase admin library with a key that will give you access through the service account. You can [generate the key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) and download it, and then point to the folder where you have saved it. (It looks like you've just inlined the information, which also works.)

The "Malformed Response" error means that no response was set. This can be due to a number of things, but generally means that your program crashed or failed to call `agent.add()` for some reason. Consult the logs of your action running for more info. (If you are using the Dialogflow Inline Editor, you can get to the logs by going to https://console.firebase.google.com/, selecting your project, selecting the "Functions" tab on the left, and selecting the "logs" tab.)

**Update** based on the code and error message.

As the error message suggests, you called `admin.initializeApp()` more than once. This should only be done when the function is first configured, rather than each time your function is called. Once initialized once - it can be used multiple times.

In your case, this can be done by moving the `require` that imports firebase-admin and the call to `admin.initializeApp()` out of the `personFacts()` function and put them both closer to the top - probably right after the other `require()` calls.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It makes it very difficult to understand what you're doing or what you've changed.  Update your original question and make a comment to say you have done so.

Comment: Answer updated, including some more debugging in the code fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186304/discussion-between-walee-and-prisoner).

Comment: Answer updated with some info about finding the logs.

Comment: could not update the question dont know why but have written the execution logs error message in the chat above

Comment: answer updated. (also updated the question with your log)

Comment: Typo on my part. The function name is `val()`. Answer updated.

Comment: Make sure your keys match. StackOverflow isn't about writing all the code for you. Understand what the code is doing and if you have questions, update your question to indicate where you are having problems.

Comment: shouldnt this be free when using Firebase Realtime Database, i got this message : .Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions.

Comment: It is. That is a warning, not an error. Please don't ask unrelated questions in comments - go ahead and ask a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: @walee you get more points for asking more questions.   Stay on topic with your current question dont edit it and change it from the original question.  Ask new questions.

Comment: @DaImTo i dont need to ask new question about this, i need to change variable, const, db, function names here for certain reasons.