# different paths for media content

Tags: javascript, css, html

I hope this is not bad question but, usually i have used 'src' for the URL or location of media like here :

```
<img id="myImg" src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
```

but just came a cross to this one

```
function showFullImage(image) {
      var image_path = ("img/0" + image + ".png");
document.getElementById('image_container').innerHTML = "<img src = '" + image_path + "' />";
      console.log(image_path);
}
```

i want to know the meaning of this part : `("img/0" + image + ".png")` is this also path ?

Comment: that's the ONLY path there... the question is: do you really need the zero after `img/`?

Comment: @DaFois need to write that i'm beginner on javascript, is this the location of image.png: image_path = ("img/0" + image + ".png"); ?

Comment: isnt image location usually like this 'src="smiley.gif" ?

Comment: the function receives the `image` parameter as filename for the image and adds a path (`img/0`) to it and a png extension to the image, after that it uses the path to change the image inside an `#image_container` element

Comment: so, if you have a small image in the `img/small/` folder and the big one in `img/big/`you can use the funcion to change the path and show the big img

Comment: this code was also next to it, could you explain how these connect : <div id = "image_container">
      <div id = "grid_view">
        <div class = "image_in_grid" onclick="showFullImage(1)">
          <img src = "img/01.png" />
        </div>
        <div class = "image_in_grid" onclick="showFullImage(2)">
          <img src = "img/02.png" />
</div>
        <div class = "image_in_grid" onclick="showFullImage(3)">
          <img src = "img/03.png" />
     </div>
         <div class = "image_in_grid" onclick="showFullImage(4)">
          <img src = "img/04.png" /></div></div></div>

Comment: it is the same as above, the function changes the `src` attribute by passing a number to the function. That number is used to create the new path...

Comment: @DaFois could you also answer this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061311/get-json-data-from-realtime-database-to-dialogflow-inline-editor-google-assista

Comment: No, i can't....

Comment: @DaFois this one is last, could you explain also what happens here : function showGridView() {var content_string = "<div id = 'grid_view'>\
<div class = 'image_in_grid' onclick='showFullImage(1)'>\<img src ='img/01.png' />\</div>\<div class = 'image_in_grid' onclick='showFullImage(2)'>\<img src = 'img/02.png' />\</div>\
<div class = 'image_in_grid' onclick='showFullImage(3)'>\ <img src = 'img/03.png' />\
      </div>\
<div class = 'image_in_grid' onclick='showFullImage(4)'>\
<img src = 'img/04.png' />\</div>\</div>";document.getElementById('image_container').innerHTML = content_string;}

Comment: it's better if open another question, comments are not to ask again, sorry